# Sitecore Setting Time for Visitor Session to Flush Data to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-analytics

As far as I understand when we use tracker to tracking the user information..

> All the data you store in Tracker, including facets, are stored in
>   visitor's session. When session ends, data is flushed to MongoDB.

But I waited for several minutes the data is not being flushed to MongoDB.. I'm connect to the site as anynomous user.. Are this have impact?

Are there setting on sitecore config to set, for visitor session to flush data to mongoDB?

I tried to close my browser to destroy the session this is also don't have impact.. Any idea guys?

Comment: In the web.config, navigate to the Sessionstate. Set the timeout to 1 instead of 20. Note this is for debug purposes. Never use this on production environment

Comment: After the session ends the data is sent to MongoDB for developent or debuging, you can create a page to kill the session, See http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/english/sitecore-tips-and-tricks-2016/ 
then you can call him if you want to flush to MongoDB